# Download multiple xls files using Python

Tags: python, csv, windows-7

I was wondering if somebody here could help me out creating a script? I have never done something like this before so I have no idea what I’m doing. But I have been reading about it for a couple days now and I’m still not understanding it so I appreciating all help I can get. I’m even willing to pay for your service!

Here is an example of my problem. I have for the moment a CSV file named “Stars” saved on my windows desktop containing around 50.000 different links that directly starts downloading a xls file when pressed. Each row contains one of these links. I would want with your help create some kind of script for this that will make some kind of loop thru each row and visit this different links so it can download these 50.000 different files.

Thank you all for taking time to read this

/ Sarah

Comment: So if you want to do this in `python`, why have you tagged the question `php`?

Comment: Oh, i'll fix it now, If it's possible to this with php it would be fine too, no need's to have it in python

Comment: @SarahPolley also remove tag `bash`. Can you provide a row structure? obfuscate a link

Comment: Removed! 
A row would look something like

http://www.nasa.com/vps/Stars/excel/print.asp?id=957474261&e=0&name=VPS_stars_Big

All links contain this text, only the numbers change

Comment: i Dont know if it was this you was talking about?
My english is not the best

Comment: @SarahPolley can we get an example link?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How much progress have you made? Are you asking for information on how to a read a file, parse CSV, open a browser from a link, or how to loop?

Comment: @TimberlakeCoding , this is not the original link but it would be something like this. I cant share the links because of the secretes issus

Comment: @verdammelt
Sadley the answer for that is all of the above..  I have some help to do this `file = readfile("file.csv);
foreach(line in file) {
  data = readfile(line);
  id = regexpmatch(line,""id=([0-9]+)&" (PCRE));
  savefile(id,data);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Say your CSV file looks like:

```
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1579.txt
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2577.txt
```

replace path to `csvfile` and `targetdir` in python code:

```
import os
import urllib2

csvfile = '/tmp/links.csv'
targetdir = '/tmp/so'

with open(csvfile) as links:
    for link in links:
        filename = link.split('/')[-1].strip()
        filepath = os.path.join(targetdir, filename)
        print 'Downloading %s \n\t .. to %s' % (link.strip(), filepath)
        with open(filepath, 'w') as data:
            xlsfile = urllib2.urlopen(link)
            data.writelines(xlsfile)
```

**Example of usage:**

```
$ python download_all.py
Downloading http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt
     .. to /tmp/so/rfc959.txt
Downloading http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1579.txt
     .. to /tmp/so/rfc1579.txt
Downloading http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2577.txt
     .. to /tmp/so/rfc2577.txt

$ dir -1 /tmp/so
rfc1579.txt
rfc2577.txt
rfc959.txt
```

Good Luck.

Comment: @SarahPolley Probably you uses in python3. Can you post a full error? Try to remove a `print` statement and escape path for windows, i.e. double backslash: `C:\\tmp\\whatever`

Comment: Now when i try to run the script in the Python IDLE i receive invalid syntax error and this -> ' <- highlighted


`code`
import os
import urllib2

csvfile = 'C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\input.csv'
targetdir = 'C:\Users\Desktop\output'

with open(csvfile) as links:
    for link in links:
        filename = link.split('/')[-1].strip()
        filepath = os.path.join(targetdir, filename)
        print 'Downloading %s \n\t .. to %s  ->  ' <-   % (link.strip(), filepath)
        with open(filepath, 'w') as data:
            xlsfile = urllib2.urlopen(link)
            data.writelines(xlsfile)
`code`

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution:

Without more information, the best answer I can give you on this question would be to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) to download the file and the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to parse your csv with the links.

Example:

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', 'PATH\TO\DOWNLOAD\DIRECTORY')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "application/csv")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

input_csv_location = "PATH\TO\CSV.csv"

with open(csv_location, 'r') as input_csv:
    reader = csv.reader(input_csv)
    for line in reader:
        driver.get(line[0])
```

This assumes there is no header on the csv and that the urls are sitting in spot numero uno.